# Overriding the Password Format in Orchard

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.10

I am trying to override the password format (e.g. Password length and complexity) of the Orchard Site. I can't seem to find anywhere in the Admin Section however I have found the `MembershipSettings` class which returns the format, however I am not sure where to override the settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you are using Orchard 1.10.2 or below, the only way to override how passwords are validated is by using your own registration controller. You cant do anything from the admin section I'm afraid

I believe the dev branch they have added many settings for password validation to the admin section, though I'm not sure using the dev branch on live is wise. I can share an example of how to override the accounts controller if you wish.

Comment: Yeah I ended up doing that, I did something similar when I wanted to change the Forgot Password Email